# React-native ListView keys

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, key, react-native

I'm getting a warning on my app that bothers me. the react keeps saying that I need to add key for each row, but no matter what I cannot add these keys.

my code looks like this:

```
 <ListView
   style={styles.listView}
   dataSource={this.state.favs}
   renderSeparator={() => <View style={styles.listSeparator}/>}
   renderRow={(rowData,i) => <Card data={rowData} 
            onPress={this.onCardPress.bind(this,rowData)} /> }
/>
```

I try to add the key on my component like this `<Card key={rowData.id}/>/`
 and I also tried to get the key from the props inside my component and add it in the first element of the component on my case is a TouchbleOpacity

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
        key={this.props.key}
        style={styles.cardBtn}>
```

Someone could hive me a hint? or should I should ignore this warning?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually `renderRow` gets four arguments `(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow)` , and you need the third and not the second one.

```
renderRow={(rowData, sectionID, rowID) => <Card key={rowID} data={rowData} 
            onPress={this.onCardPress.bind(this,rowData)} /> }
```

Reference: [facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow)

Comment: thanks @Cherniv, silly mistake, I also realised I need to add a key to the renderSeparator

Answer (score 6):

As stated by Gabriel Lopes in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227815/react-native-listview-keys#comment58173889_35229429), a common mistake is to forget to add keys to the separators.

So make sure they are added. You can build them from the arguments passed to the separator function:

```js
renderSeparator(sectionId, rowId, adjacentRowHighlighted) {
  return (<View key={`sep:${sectionId}:${rowId}`} />);
}
```