# How do you access a rowID in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-listview

[I'm simply trying to access the number value in the row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJf8e.png)

[Here is my code for it. When I click on the row. I want the row to be able to identify it's number so that I can pass it to another view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HEOM.png)

Comment: never never never post your code as a screenshot!! you can post it in the body of your question or even better if you create a working example on rnplay.org

Comment: answering your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227815/react-native-listview-keys/35229429#35229429

Comment: @Cherniv oh sorry, didn't know that was a bad thing

Answer (score 3):

There is a good tutorial at the official react-native site: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

In `renderRow` callback you receive 4 parameters `(rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow)` - so just pass `rowID` to your `TouchableHighlight` handler:

```
renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
    <TouchableHighlight
       onPress={this.goToStats.bind(this, rowID)}
       ...
```